# Generating a Rig using rigify keeps creating this error?

Tags: rigging, error, rigify

The character I'm rigging for is very simple and only requires basic eye controls, but whenever I delete the unnecessary bones and try to generate, I get this error:

**Generation has thrown an exception: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "ORG-nose" not found'**

[image]

I've tried keeping the nose bones as well, but the error then changes to the lips, or the ears, depending on which is left. As far as I can tell, the eye bones are still parented to the main face control, and if I delete this main face control, the rig generates without the eye controls.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The face sample is a whole piece, so you have to generate the rig with all of its components (or without the whole face).

Then, after generating, you can turn on visibility of all bone layers, select in edit mode all bones related with nose, lips, cheecks, ... and delete them.